# How to skip first element in `for` loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

Is there a robust, universal way in python to skip first element in the `for` loop?

The only way I can think of is to write a special generator by hand:

```
def skipFirst( it ):
    it = iter(it) #identity for iterators
    it.next()
    for x in it:
        yield x
```

And use it for example like:

```
for x in skipFirst(anIterable):
    print repr(x)
```

and like:

```
doStuff( str(x) for x in skipFirst(anIterable) )
```

and like:

```
[ x for x in skipFirst(anIterable) if x is not None ]
```

I know we can do slices on lists `(x for x in aList[1:])` but this makes a copy and does not work for all sequences, iterators, collections etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When skipping just *one* item, I'd use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
it = iter(iterable_or_sequence)
next(it, None)  # skip first item.
for elem in it:
    # all but the first element
```

By giving it a second argument, a default value, it'll also swallow the `StopIteration` exception. It doesn't require an import, can simplify a cluttered `for` loop setup, and can be used *in* a `for` loop to conditionally skip items.

If you were expecting to *iterate* over all elements of `it` skipping the first item, then [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is appropriate:

```
from itertools import islice

for elem in islice(it, 1, None):
    # all but the first element
```

Comment: Using the builtin `next` also has the advantage of working in both Python2 and Python3. Python3 renames the `it.next()` special method to `it.__next__()`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: yup, **and** you don't have to catch the `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: right, that's the thing that my thing was "also" to :-) The questioner's code doesn't catch `StopIteration`, but should...

Answer (score 23):

```
for i in list1[1:]: #Skip first element
    # Do What Ever you want
```

**Explanation:**

When you use [1:] in for loop list it skips the first element and start loop from second element to last element

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Explanation : for i in list1[1:]: 
When you use [1:] in for loop list it skips the first element and start loop from second element to last element.

Comment: This solution is not correct, it does not skip element, but makes a copy without first element. Probably not what user wants to do.

Comment: You don’t want to do this if the list is large. You *can’t* do this if the object in question isn’t a sequence (not a list or tuple or string or similar), but is instead just an iterable.

Comment: +1 This was the correct answer for me, just overwrite the original list:
`list1 = list1[1:]`
`for i in list:`
`# do stuff here`

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't generalize. For example, `for i in reversed(list1[1:]):` skips the wrong element.

Answer (score 6):

I think [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) will do the trick:

```
islice( anIterable, 1, None )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def skip_first(iterable):
    """Short and sweet"""

    return (element for i, element in enumerate(iterable) if i)

def skip_first_faster(iterable):
    """Faster, but meh"""

    generator = (element for element in iterable)
    next(generator, None) # None Prevents StopIteration from being raised

    return generator

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in skip_first(range(5)):
        print item

    for item in skip_first_faster(range(5)):
        print item
```

Comment: Don’t use a generator expression here. `iter()` is much more efficient and produces an iterator that doesn’t have to resort to a Python `for` construct just to loop.